# operation could not be completed com.facebook.sdk error 3 - IOS-react-native-FBSDK

Tags: ios, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I am facing an issue with facebook login `operation could not be completed com.facebook.sdk error 3` I don't have any clue to fix up this issue. Attaching my code snippets of Info.plist, Appdelidate.m and my button

Here is my **Info.plist** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>myappname</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <!--See http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/ -->
    <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <!-- For Facebook -->
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb1922460507874734</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>1922460507874734</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>MyappnamefromFacebook</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fb</string>
      <string>fbapi</string>
      <string>fbauth2</string>
      <string>fbshareextension</string>
      <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And my **AppDelegate.m** file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"myappname"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  // return YES;
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  // return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
    annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
  ];
  // Add any custom logic here.
  // return handled;
}

@end
```

And finally my button

```
<LoginButton
          onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
              if (error) {
                // alert(result)
                alert("Login failed with error: " + error.message);
              } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                alert("Login was cancelled");
              } else {
                alert("Login was successful with permissions: " + result.grantedPermissions)
              }
            }
      }
      onLogoutFinished={() => alert("User logged out")}/>
```

Above code currently display the button, upon clicking on the button it throws error attached the error message.

[image]

Here is also my Facebook dashboard about IOS platform [image]

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be problem with FBSDK version 4.39.0 updating the below versions solved my problem

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.38.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.38.1'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.38.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on their repo https://github.com/facebook/facebook-objc-sdk/releases, 4.38 is marked as the latest release. There are URL encoding / decoding changes in the commits history. URLs are broken in the 4.39 release, that's why 4.39 is not the latest recommended version, however, it is still in the podspec.

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.38.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.38.0'
```